# SharePoint 2013 Site Collection Move Owner to Group

Tags: 2013, security, export, user, import

I am in process of migrating our WSS 3.0 installation to 2013 and I am at the point where I need to break the single site collection down into more manageable sizes and I have a script that categorizes our sites into our different business areas.  This works great.  BUT, when I execute the command to create a new site collection, I am required to specify an owner.  So, I put my login as the owner.  Now, I am also exporting the existing sites and importing them into the new collections and including security.

The problem I am having is that the owner (me) is listed separately under security for each site and site collection when all I want is the existing security to remain after the import of a site.  I created a script that would locate a user throughout a site collection and remove them but it will not allow me to remove the owner of a web site collection.  My end goal is to have myself in a group and not as an individual user for the sites.  Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are trying to remove yourself as yourself? A script or a manual removal ran as a server administrator or another Site Collection Administrator should be able to accomplish this.

The script itself will be very basic.